# Number theory in symmetric cryptography

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

One of the most famous application of number theory is the RSA cryptosystem, which essentially initiated asymmetric cryptography.

I wonder if there are applications of number theory also in **symmetric** cryptography.

Thank you in advance for any comment / reference.

**NOTE:** Since RSA is based on [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), I'm looking for applications of number theory to symmetric cryptography that involve number-theoretic theorems at least as "complex" as Euler's theorem. For example, I do not consider [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) as an application of number theory to symmetric cryptography, because it uses only the most basic definition of modular arithmetic.

Comment: [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) uses addition, multiplication and multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb{F}_{256}$. Is that number theoretic and more than "most basic" arithmetic?

Comment: @JohannesHahn But does AES use some number-theoretic theorem?

Comment: Well that's what I'm asking you. Is the theorem that a field with 256 elements exists, number-theoretic enough for you? Is it more than "most basic" arithmetic?

Comment: By the way: Since most symmetric ciphers that occur in the "real world" are designed to be as fast as possible on current computer hardware, they don't often use complicated functions. Instead they rely on "simple" functions derived from bit manipulation and basic arithmetic and combine them in clever ways. This does not preclude that some examples of what you're looking for do exist, but it makes it seem a bit less likely to me.

Comment: @JohannesHahn It is worth mentioning that the "real" speed improvement which makes symmetric ciphers fast is that of hardware implementation. I believe AES gets a ~40 times speed increase when run in hardware vs software, for example.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, AES-GCM (Galois Counter Mode) is maybe an even better example (since another finite field, and more number-theoretical arguments, appear in the "GCM" part) - and it's certainly high-speed and practical.

Comment: Pohlig-Helman cipher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few interesting examples of *symmetric* primitives whose claimed security is/was based on number-theoretic problems:

1. From the 1980s: the famous [Blum-Blum-Shub deterministic random bit generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) is a classic example.  Let $N = pq$ be the product of two large safe primes, and consider the sequence defined by $x_{i+1} = x_i^2 \pmod{N}$, where $x_0$ is the random seed (which can be any value in $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times\setminus\{1\}$).  After each squaring, you extract some of the bits of $x_i$ to form the pseudorandom stream.  The security of the bit generator - that is, the indistinguishability from a uniform random stream - can be reduced to number-theoretic problems.  The idea is that if you only take the least significant bit of $x_i$ (or up to $O(\log\log N)$) at each iteration, then breaking this generator reduces to solving the Quadratic Rediduosity Problem $\bmod N$.
2. A second classic example (this time from the 1990s): the [KN cipher (Knudsen-Nyberg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KN-Cipher) was a number-theoretic block cipher designed specifically to resist differential cryptanalysis.  The cipher was applied to 64-bit blocks, and the round function was defined as follows: choose a basis of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{37}}$ where the operation $x \mapsto x^3$ is particularly efficient.  Let $E: \mathbb{F}_{2}^{32}: \to \mathbb{F}_{2^{37}}$ be some affine map, and let $F: \mathbb{F}_{2^{37}} \to \mathbb{F}_{2}^{32}$ be the map defined by cubing in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{37}}$, followed by throwing away five coefficients of the polynomial representation (w.r.t. the "nice cubing" basis).  Now, dividing the 64-bit cipher state into two 32-bit values $L$ and $R$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^{32}$, the round function is $(L,R) \mapsto (R,L+F(E(R)+K))$, where $K \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{37}}$ is the secret key.  The nonlinearity of the cubing permutation is important.  The KN-cipher was subsequently broken using higher-order differential cryptanalysis, but its ideas have proven influential: the more recent [MiMC cipher](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/492.pdf), for example, revisits the KN-cipher targeting applications in multi-party computation and zero-knowledge proofs.
3. An example from the 2000s using "deeper" results in number theory: the [Charles-Goren-Lauter hash function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/021).  Here we consider the $2$-isogeny graph of supersingular $j$-invariants over a suitably large $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$: this is an important example of a Ramanujan graph, and this is key to the construction.  The bits of the message $(m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ drive a non-backtracking walk of length $n$ in the isogeny graph (which is $(2+1)$-regular, so at each step you have $2$ choices: "low" or "high" w.r.t. some ordering on $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, and you go "low" if $m_i = 0$ and "high" if $m_i = 1$).  The final hash value is a projection of the ending point $j_n$ of your walk into $\mathbb{F}_p$.  The security of the hash function reduces to problems connected with finding cycles in the isogeny graph, which are provably large.
4. **Edit** (I forgot one of my favourites): Wegman-Carter authenticators, which give high-performance MACs (message authentication codes) with information-theoretic security.  Here, take a $\ge k$-bit finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and fix an inclusion $\iota: \{0,1\}^k \to \mathbb{F}_q$ (everything will operate on $k$-bit chunks of data) and a mapping $\pi: \mathbb{F}_{q} \to \{0,1\}^t$ (this will produce a $t$-bit MAC).  For each $n > 0$, we can define a map $(\{0,1\}^k)^n \to \mathbb{F}_q[X]$ by $$M = (M_1,\ldots,M_n) \mapsto f_M(X) := \iota(M_n)X^n + \cdots + \iota(M_1).$$ Now to produce (and verify) an authenticator for a message $M$ given a shared secret $(R \in \{0,1\}^k, S \in \{0,1\}^t)$, we compute $T = f_M(R)\oplus S$ (where $\oplus$ denotes XOR in $\{0,1\}^t$).  A crucial part of the security argument depends on the distribution of evaluations of polynomials over finite fields (see e.g. [Bernstein 2005](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2005/34940166/34940166.pdf) for an up-to-date description and analysis of this).

In all four examples, number-theoretic arguments are used to give strong justifications for the security of the primitive.  But the last example is important because it is also used in practice: the Wegman-Carter construction can be seen in GHASH, which is used in [AES-GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (in this case, $q$ is a power of $2$), and it is also the basis of [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305), a high-speed software authenticator.  AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 are two state-of-the-art algorithms for Authenticated Encryption that are widely used on the internet today.

Answer (score 11):

The non-linearity in the block cipher AES comes from the pseudo-inversion function on the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$, defined by

$$ p(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1} & \text{if $x \not=0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=0$.}\end{cases} $$

It is a nice exercise to show that $p$ is as strong as possible against the difference attack. That is, given any non-zero $\Delta \in \mathbb{F}_{2^8}$, the function $Dp_\Delta : \mathbb{F}_{2^8} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^8}$ defined by

$$Dp_\Delta(x) = p(x) + p(x + \Delta) $$

takes $2^7-1$ different values, and is $2$ to $1$, except for an exceptional set of size $4$, namely $\{0,\Delta,\beta\Delta,(1+\beta)\Delta\}$ where $\beta$ is a solution to $\beta^2+\beta+1 = 0$, all of whose elements are sent to $\Delta^{-1}$. Not especially deep, but it's a nice application of the theory of quadratic equations in fields of characteristic two, so arguably number-theoretic. (Anyway I like it, because I discovered it for myself when asked to lecture undergraduate cryptography.)

The linear cryptanalysis of AES, by approximating the AES functions with $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear maps suggested by the Discrete Fourier Transform, seems to be somewhat trickier: see for instance this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/12548783.pdf) by Kenichi Sakamura, Wang Xiao Dong and Hirofumi Ishikawa.

Comment: Incidentally, if anyone has any suggestions for an undergraduate-friendly non-linear function that has an extremely simple theory of either differential- or linear-cryptanalysis, please let me know, and it will be very welcome as I deliver the revamped course using 'active blended learning' this term.

Comment: $x^3$ is a little simpler than $1/x$ (still in char $2$). $x^3 + (x+d)^3 = dx^2+d^2x+d^3$ is quadratic so at most $2$ to $1$.

Comment: Incidentally, $x^3$ has recently been revisited as a source of non-linearity to design block ciphers (for use in the development of STARKS), in particular [MiMC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/492.pdf). The resistance to differential/linear cryptanalysis seems to be fairly simple to show (half a page on page 14), although there is a [higher-order differential analytic attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/182) over binary fields.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $Dp_\Delta(x) = p(x + \Delta) - p(x)$? Oh yeah, characteristic 2 means they're equivalent

Comment: Thank you Felipe Voloch. In fact the derivative is $2$ to $1$ with no exceptional set: $dx^2 + d^2x + d^3 = e$ if and only if $y^2+y+1 = e/d^3$ where $y = x/d$, and the function $y \mapsto y^2+y+1$ is $2$ to $1$, with fibres $\{y,y+1\}$. So it's even better than pseudo-inversion: the image of the derivative has size $2^7$, not $2^7-1$, and this really is the maximum possible, since always $x$ and $x + d$ have the same image. Alas $x \mapsto x^3$ is not a drop-in replacement for $p$ in AES, because cubing is not injective on the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$.

Comment: Hi Mark, very nice discussion. It meant I didn't need to include this topic in my answer.

Comment: 20 years ago (standardization of AES) the differential optimality of $x\mapsto x^{254}$ (your $p(x)$) on $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$ was a still a conjecture. Is it now kown that
differentially 2-uniform permutations of $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$ do not exist?

Comment: @esg, I believe that's still open. I just did a quick search as a sanity check: it is stated as open in papers published in 2020.

Answer (score 6):

The book *Stream Ciphers and Number Theory* by Cusick, Ding and Renvall is devoted to this topic, stream ciphers being one kind of symmetric cipher. I give some examples from there that are not that well known.

One security measure for a keystream output by a stream cipher is its *linear complexity*, i.e., the lowest order linear recurrence which it satisfies. This is usually obtained by the Berlekamp Massey algorithm applied to the output, and must be high with respect to the period of the sequence, since Berlekamp Massey is an efficient recursive algorithm.

The *sphere complexity* of a sequence is a generalization; it is the minimal value of the linear complexity, if an adversary can flip $k$ bits of the sequence?

A basic result that is used in this text is the following.

Let $N=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_t^{e_t},$ where $p_i$ are $t$ pairwise distinct primes, and $q$ is a positive integer (power of a prime) such that $\gcd(q,N)=1.$ Then for each nonconstant sequence $s$ of period $N$ over $GF(q)$,
$$
L(s)\geq \min\{ord_{p_1}(q),\ldots,ord_{p_t}(q)\}
$$
and
$$
SC_k(s)\geq \min \{ord_{p_1}(q),\ldots,ord_{p_t}(q)\},
$$
if $k<\min\{WH(s),N-WH(s)\}.$ Here $WH$ is the Hamming weight of the sequence $s$ $L(s)$ is its linear complexity, $SC_k(s)$ is its sphere complexity under $k$ bitflips, and $ord(\cdot)$ denotes multiplicative order.

Also note that one can define a power generator in $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ via choosing an initial setting $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ and letting $a_{t+1} = a_t^d \pmod N.$ For $d=2,$ this is the Blum Blum Shub generator, and has some nice security properties if $p,q$ are both congruent to 3 modulo 4, though a bit slow to be used directly as a keystream in modern symmetric cryptography. One can prove that if we only take the least significant $k$ bits of each $a_t$ as an output block of bits,  provided $k\leq \log N,$ breaking this keystream (determining the initial loading) is equivalent to factoring $N.$

The classical theory of binary Linear Shift Register Sequences and their nonlinear filterings, as pioneered by Golomb in his book *Shift Register Sequences* and extended further is another example, however this is not explicitly or deeply number theoretic in nature, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

[Lattice-based Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice-based_cryptography) (where "lattice" is in the sense of Euclidean lattices) can be used to develop both symmetric and asymmetric primitives.
One particularly interesting example is the [SWIFTT](https://www.alonrosen.net/PAPERS/lattices/swifft.pdf) compression function.
For a *quick* summary of this function, it essentially takes the form of:

$$f(\vec{b}) = A\mathcal{F}(\vec{b})$$
Where $\vec{b}$ is a bit-vector of suitable dimension, $\mathcal{F}$ is the discrete Fourier transform on $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ a prime, and $A$ is a (fixed) matrix, which one computes a matrix-vector product with.

Compression functions can be used in standard ways to build cryptographic hash functions (for example, the [Merkle-Damgard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction)). The authors found that their compression function is roughly competitive with software implementations of standard hash functions (for example SHA256), at 40MB/s throughput (SWIFTT) vs 47MB/s (SHA256). SWIFTT has some slightly odd properties (it is easy to see that $f$ is a linear function. SWIFTT guards against collisions by mandating that each entry of $\vec{b}$ is in $\mathbb{F}_p\cap \{0,1\}$, which is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb{F}_p$).

A common optimization within lattice-based cryptography is not to work with *Euclidean* lattices, but instead *ideal lattices*, which correspond to ideals in algebraic number fields (most commonly, the ring of integers of some cyclotomic of degree $2^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$). This is entirely analogous to how in coding theory certain classes of codes (for example "cyclic codes") can be interpreted as ideals in certain quotients of polynomial rings.

This leads to additional algebraic structure, which speeds up implementations (usually by an order $O(n)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the lattice. For practical numbers, think roughly in the range of $\approx 500$ to $\approx 30,000$, depending on the application).
But this additional algebraic structure can also be used to *attack* the underlying assumed computationally hard problem.

The number theory required for the *discussion* of these algorithms is not that deep (although deeper than things like RSA). It mainly involves discussing different operations one can perform in algebraic number fields (although the computational efficiency of such operations is quite important). Investigating the security impact of the additional assumption of algebraic structure can be more intensive. This [recent paper](https://iacr.org/cryptodb/data/paper.php?pubkey=30425) (which has some very nice animations describing their work) proves a certain "quick mixing" lemma for random walks in the Arkelov class group of a number field, which is then used to prove tighter bounds on the security of ideal lattice-based cryptography. There have been similar papers (such as [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/313.pdf)), which give somewhat better (sub-exponential vs fully exponential) attacks against certain problems on ideal lattices, again by leveraging more number theory than things like RSA (I believe they use some results regarding the Stickelberg ideal).

This is all to say that any lattice-based symmetric scheme is an answer to your question due to the number theory required to prove the security of using ideal lattices, and certain exist (say SWIFTT) which are competitive with software implementations of "standard" symmetric schemes.